# Problem on "Distribution" of conditional expectation w.r.t a sigma field

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $Y$ be a random variable s.t. $E|Y|<\infty$. Let $E[Y|\mathcal{G}]$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. I need to prove that $E[Y|\mathcal{G}]=Y$ a.s. How does one use the fact that a random variable and its conditional expectation has the same distribution ?

Comment: "How does one use the fact that a random variable and its conditional expectation has the same value ?" Hopefully your proof won't use this "fact" since this is not the hypothesis.

Comment: @Did: sorry, same distribution, not value.